# Nested react hooks exposing static references

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I was looking the implementation of [eslint-plugin-react-hooks](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/79a25125b19c2d6deaf03d4ab0dfdd6082377d97/packages/eslint-plugin-react-hooks/src/ExhaustiveDeps.js) and it looks like `useState`'s `setState` and `useReducer`'s `dispatch` functions are static references which are not required to be declared in the dependency array in `useEffect`.

However, this rule does not seem to work properly when you write a custom rule that abstracts an internal logic. for example, I create a custom hook:

```
const useCustom = () => {
    const [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
    return [number, setNumber];
};
```

which is then used the following way:

```
const [number, setNumber] = useCustom();
React.useEffect(() => {
   if (something) {
       setNumber(1);
   }
}, [something]); // useEffect has a missing dependency: 'setNumber'
```

Adding the dependency to the array does not seem to cause extra render cycles. However, it raises a another question: **What if my hook returns a reference to an value returned from `useRef()` would that be safe to add it to the dependencies array?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value from useRef will never change unless you unmount and remount the component.

Changing value.current will not cause the component to re render but if the value.current is a dependency of your effect then your effect will re run when the component re renders.

Not sure if this answers your question, I added sample code below to demonstrate:

```js
const useTimesRendered = () => {
  const rendered = React.useRef(0);
  rendered.current++;
  return rendered;
};
const useCustomRef = () => {
  const customRef = React.useRef(0);
  return customRef;
};
const App = () => {
  const rendered = useTimesRendered();
  const custom = useCustomRef();
  const [, reRender] = React.useState({});
  React.useEffect(
    () => console.log('rendered ref only on mount', rendered.current),
    [rendered]
  );
  const customVal = custom.current;
  React.useEffect(
    () => console.log('custom ref.current only when re rendering', customVal),
    [customVal]
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Times rendered: {rendered.current}</h1>
      <button onClick={() => custom.current++}>
        increase custom
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => reRender({})}>
        Re render app
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: would it be safe to add `const custom` to the dependency array. I know that in this case it does not make much sense but in my use case this `useRef()` is abstracted from the hook user?

Comment: @KirillKulakov As you can see with `rendered` the effect is not run again. The effect for `custom.current ` stored as `customVal` will run again but not necessarily when `customVal` changes, only when it changed and App is re rendered. Setting a dependency to an effect with the return value of `useRef` (not the value.current) will have the effect not re run because that value never changes (you can mutate it by setting value.current but it doesn't change value). So if it's "safe" depends on what behaviour you expect versus how it will behave. I can only explain how it will behave.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your question correctly, than will go with yes. If ref never changes (capturing some node on component mount), or if it changes frequetly (like in `usePrevious` hook) it should be added to the list of dependencies. Only potential issue I could think of is when someone, for example use ref on input and than expect that will get a new updated ref after user type somenthing. But that is a topic for some other time